# JavaScript - Regular expression to convert image source

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress, mootools

My question is related only to JavaScript regular expressions.

I'm building a simple Lightbox for Wordpress with Mootools JavaScript framework.

Wordpress stores pictures in a variety of sizes with file names like:

```
'image-50-50x100.jpg'
'image-50-150x100.jpg'
'image-50-1024x698.jpg'
'image-50.jpg'
```

When a user clicks a thumbnail image, I have to convert the source of that image into the source of full size image, and then preload that full-size image.

**The question**

How to change string like this:

```
'http://some-path/image-50-50x100.jpg'
'http://some-path/image-50-150x100.jpg'
'http://some-path/image-50-1024x698.jpg'
'http://some-path/image-50.jpg'
```

,  into:

```
'http://some-path/image-50.jpg'
```

Missing piece is accurate regular-expression in code below:

```
source.replace( /regular-expression/, '' );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So...read up on regular expressions. :-) (Although this doesn't strictly need them, using them would probably be the cleaner solution.) What have you actually *tried*?

Comment: Also this doesn't necessarily require regular expressions. Substrings could do too... I discourage use of regular expressions for simple cases like this since they actually require more work to be done behind the scenes. (No reference article for that now, but if you want one, I can search for one...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
str = str.replace(/-\d+x\d+/, '');
```

E.g.:

```
var str = 'http://some-path/image-50-1024x698.jpg';
str = str.replace(/-\d+x\d+/, '');
console.log(str); // "http://some-path/image-50.jpg"
```

And for the case where you don't want it to change, it doesn't:

```
var str = 'http://some-path/image-50.jpg';
str = str.replace(/-\d+x\d+/, '');
console.log(str); // "http://some-path/image-50.jpg"
```

---

**Edit**: You've said in a comment elsewhere that:

> In some rare cases it can happen that Wordpress user uploads image like `image-1024x698.jpg`, then Wordpress creates thumb image like `image-1024x698-300x300.jpg`

Okay, so we add `\.` and `.` to the above:

```
var str = 'http://some-path/image-1024x698-300x300.jpg';
str = str.replace(/-\d+x\d+\./, '.');
console.log(str); // "http://some-path/image-1024x698.jpg"
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, now I've noticed that I used the first regex from @ Ryan Lynch: `path.replace( /(.+)-(\d+x\d+)\.([^\.]+)$/, '$1.$3' )`, not the altered one, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
source.replace(/(.+\/[^-]+-[^-]+)(-\d+x\d+)*\.([^\.]+)$/, '$1.$3')
```

Comment: Surely that's *much* more complicated than required.

Comment: Come up with a simpler one then.

Comment: Now it does, I changed it. See @T.J Crowder's answer though, its much better.

Comment: In some rare cases it can happen that Wordpress user uploads image like `image-1024x698.jpg`, then Wordpress creates thumb image like `image-1024x698-300x300.jpg`, in that case answer from @T.J. Crowder will not work.